# Borel-Weil-Bott Theorem step

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ a real algebraic group and $T$ a borel subgroup, $G_C$ be the complexification of $G$ and $B$ be the borel subgroup of $G_C$ corresponding to $T$.
In [Woit's Borel Weil Bott's notes](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/notes16.pdf), Woit claims that $G_C/B = G/T$(he cryptically says as spaces of right cosets.)  I don't think this is true even on the level of sets.

Let $G=GL(2, \mathbb{R})$.  Then $G/T\cong P(\wedge^1(\mathbb{R}^2))$ where this is an isomorphism of quasi projective varieties, and where $P$ denotes projectivization.  $G/T$ is a priori given the structure of a quasi projective variety by taking an action on a well chosen projective space and using the fact that the orbits are locally closed.  Similarly $G_C/B\cong P(\wedge^1(\mathbb{C}^2))$.

On the level of sets we have explicitly if $e_1, e_2$ are canonical bases for $\mathbb{C}^2$, that $G(e_1 ,e_1 \wedge e_2)$ is the full flag variety on $\mathbb{R}^2$ sitting in the flag variety of $\mathbb{C}^2$.   The Borel, $T$ of $G$ is the stabilizer of this point and is the real upper triangular matrices.  If we take $G_C(e_1 ,e_1 \wedge e_2)$ this is the full flag variety on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and the stabilizer of this point is exactly the $B$ that corresponds to $T$.  The orbit under $G_C$ strictly contains the orbit under $G$.